# Raspberry Pi is not detecting the KY-001 Temperature Sensors

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am trying to use a **KY-001 Temperature Sensor** for a project than I am working on. This is my first time working with a Raspberry pi, so I might have made a rookie mistake, but I cannot tell what I am doing wrong. I have tried following several tutorials for the DS18B20 and other troubleshooting, but all I can get the sensor to show is 00-and some random letters or numbers. I have added dtoverlay=w1-gpio, gpiopin=4 to my boot/config.txt, and attached is an image of my set up (Power plugged into pin 1, Ground into pin 6, Data into pin 7).
[My set up of the raspberry pi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4Kyd.jpg)

Comment: What language are you using? and maybe show the code?

Comment: Hey Emil! Welcome to SO. When you say "other troubleshooting", can you be more specific? As @ChrisCatignani mentioned, you're much more likely to receive some assistance here if you show us the code you're currently using and what you've already tried.

Comment: I haven't been able to code the sensor yet as my pi doesn't recognize that it is plugged in. By troubleshooting, I mean that I have been trying different set-ups for the sensor, as on different sources, the way they plug it in has a small variation.